# Is it possible to create a job from within a DBMS_SCHEDULER job?

Tags: oracle

Creating a job from within a job using DBMS_JOB throws an:

```
ORA-32317: cannot run a job from a job
```

Does anyone know if this restriction has been lifted in DBMS_SCHEDULER?

Comment: what r u trying to do exactly?  dbms_scheduler has the concept of chains, which is a set of jobs that run either concurrently or sequentially depending on how chain rules are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.create_job  
 (job_name => 'TEST1',  
  job_type=> 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  job_action=>'BEGIN dbms_scheduler.create_job  
              (job_name => ''TEST2'',  
               job_type=> ''PLSQL_BLOCK'',
               job_action=>''DECLARE v_result NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT 1 INTO v_result FROM dual; END;'',  
               start_date=>SYSDATE,
               repeat_interval=>''FREQ=DAILY'',
               end_date=>SYSDATE+1,
               enabled=>true,  
               auto_drop=>false,  
               comments=>''Job submitted FROM a job''); end;',  
  start_date=>SYSDATE,
  repeat_interval=>'FREQ=DAILY',
  end_date=>SYSDATE+1,
  enabled=>true,  
  auto_drop=>false,  
  comments=>'Job to submit a job');  
END;
```

This demonstrates the concept. You could call a procedure instead of an inline PL/SQL block to do your job submittal. Clearly you can adjust any or all of the parameters to the create_job procedure. I would guess you could spawn a job that spawns yet another job.